# Understanding a for loop in Pine Script that seems to exceed the size of an array

Tags: pine-script

I am working with a Pine Script code snippet from KernelFunctions which uses a for loop to iterate through an array. The loop declaration is as follows:

**`for i = 0 to _size + startAtBar`**

**Here _size is the size of the input array and startAtBar is an additional offset.** This declaration seems to suggest that the loop would attempt to access indices that are beyond the size of the array. How is this possible?

When I attempted to modify the loop declaration to subtract startAtBar from _size as follows:

```
for i = 0 to _size - startAtBar
```

I received an error message stating Invalid number of bars back [-1] within the history-referencing operator. The value must be >= 0.

Below is the complete function for context:

```
pinescript
Copy code
export rationalQuadratic(series float _src, simple int _lookback, simple float _relativeWeight, simple int startAtBar) =>
    float _currentWeight = 0.
    float _cumulativeWeight = 0.
    _size = array.size(array.from(_src))
    for i = 0 to _size + startAtBar
        y = _src[i]
        w = math.pow(1 + (math.pow(i, 2) / ((math.pow(_lookback, 2) * 2 * _relativeWeight))), -_relativeWeight)
        _currentWeight += y*w
        _cumulativeWeight += w
    yhat = _currentWeight / _cumulativeWeight
    that
```

Can someone explain how the original for loop works and why my modification leads to an error? Thank you.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i = 0 to _size - startAtBar  
    y = _src[i]
```

if `size` is 0, and `startAtBar` is 1, then `for` loop is decremented, and  y = _src[-1]. But `_srs` variable cannot have -1 barsback, this value should be positive.
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Arrays.html#history-referencing